# Защита rdp сервера

Tags: c#, защита, rdp

Вопрос глуп возможно, однако уже не знаю что делать.

Дано:

- RDP сервер
- Пачка клиентов
- Защита от брута со стороны сервера
- Со стороны клиента программа которая по паролю создает rdp соединение при выключении очищает историю rdp
- Поменен порт rdp входящий
- Программа обфусцированна

Надо:

- Каким то образом защитить ip адрес сервера что бы когда "не хорошие" люди возьмут компьютер не могли его определить(ну или по крайней мере им это было сделать сложно)

P.S.

Программа написана на VisualStudio

Comment: если нужно защититься от подбора пароля к RDP, просто выставьте в настройках сервера количество попыток авторизации, после которого учетная запись блокируется, и естественно, у вас должна быть не "засвеченная" учетка для отмены блокировки забывчивых пользователей. От брута спасает железно, а вот спрятать сервер не получится, как уже написали в ответах - это можно проследить по логам маршрутизаторов.

Answer (score 1):

Эм-м-м, использовать какой-то промежуточный сервер(-а): proxy, vpn, tor, etc . Я, например, в любом случае смогу узнать куда Ваша программа ломится банально послушав трафик компьютера. Другой вариант - захардкодить в программе-клиенте IP-адрес и инициализировать соединение с сервером только после какой-нибудь десятикратной авторизации паролем, СМС, чем_угодно_ещё.

Comment: программа начинает ломиться после ввода пароля. Сервер за бугром

Answer (score 1):

Если реально захотят докопаться - просто посмотрят логи роутера, на какой IP лезет программа. Даже квалификации аникейщика на это хватит.
Самый разумный способ - прокси на другом сервере (например за пределами страны). Можно еще VPN добавить.